# Call android's audiotrack to output custom square wave data, why is my square wave output wrong?

Tags: android, audio, waveform, wave, audiotrack

I am using the android audiotrack to output a square wave, check that the data generated by the square wave is not abnormal, but why is it outputting a horn waveform?

[image]

I checked all the possibilities, but I still don't know what went wrong. I confirm that the data can output a square wave, but the waveform of the android phone output will occasionally become this flared waveform. Is it related to the function or parameter of audioTrackF.write?

```
int afw = audioTrackF.write(mbitDateF, 0, mbitDateF.length, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING);
```

Comment: Unlikely to be a problem with your `write()` call. Kinda looks like the system may be "fading in" the audio. Not sure why. 10ms seems like a rather quick fade-in, if some sort of audio ducking was taking place. How does the vertical deflection in the image compare to the deflection of the wave when it is working properly?

Comment: Thanks @greeble31, i was inspired to change the audiotrack's pause to stop. It works fine. This may be related to the audiotrack's pause mechanism. The audiotrack's pause mechanism may be faded.

Comment: However, I still can't completely determine the root cause of the problem.